# How to substitute a libm.a math function?

Tags: c, netbeans, clion, sqrt, libm

I want to test a new sqrt function to be used instead of the libm one. But both CLion and Netbeans use the libm one instead of mine (there is no need to say them to add -lm in linking).

For instance:

```
#include stdio.h>

double sqrt(double n) {
    printf("Starting\n");
    return 1.0;
}

int main () {
    printf("Root: %f\n", sqrt(4));
    return 0;
}
```

In Netbeans and CLion, this code does not execute my sqrt (never prints 'Starting' and returns 1.0). Instead, it executes sqrt in libm.a (even though math.h is not included), printing 2.0.

Is there any way to exclude -lm in linking in these IDEs?  Do I have to change my function name (it works fine If I do so)?

Alberto

Comment: You could control it with a macro.  Define `sqrt` to be either `sqrt` or `my_sqrt` to select which one your code uses.  That way both versions can coexist.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add a [mre], i.e. the source code and the commands that are run to compile and link your program.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Tom Karzes, but there is no problem if I change the name of my sqrt function (for instance to sqroot). May be such change is the best option, but I would like to know if there is a way to use the same name (sqrt), instructing the IDE to use mine and not libm one.

Comment: @AlbertoGilSolla Right, which is why I suggested using a macro.  That way all your code can use `sqrt`, and you can switch between yours and the library version simply by changing the macro. without any name conflicts.  That was the whole point.  Both functions coexist without conflicting.  The macro controls which one is called.